# Can I get log4net to append the real class name and not the generated closure class name?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a class that is logging from an anonymous method. I've dumbed it down to make the point...

```
public class SocketFlusher
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SocketFlusher));

    public void Flush()
    {
        Wait.For(timeout, () => 
        {
            ... // work
            Log.DebugFormat("{0} bytes available", socket.Available);
        }
    }
}
```

My log4net configuration is good (I've checked the log4net `debug="true"` output and the appender *does* work). My appender layout is

```
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%-4thread] %-5level %class{1} - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
```

But, my log output has that crazy auto-generated static class in it.

```
2011-03-21 18:10:20,053 [5   ] DEBUG SocketFlusher+<>c__DisplayClass1 - 82 bytes available
```

**I want it to say `SocketFlusher`, what is the right appender layout to get this format?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want the *class name* to appear in the appender output. And you're following the log4net idiom of naming your logger the name of the class...

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof($CLASSNAME$));
```

What you want to do in the appender pattern layout is to include the `%logger` name pattern instead of the `%class` pattern.

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%-4thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline"/>
</layout>
```